# How do you use a String array as a member field in a Grails domain?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to create a basic grails domain object and for one of the fields I want to use an array of Strings.  However even after running grails generate-views I still don't see the ability to edit said array.  Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: what does GORM do with it when generating the database table?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for you to put a String array as a domain class field ? Wouldn't it be cleaner for you to define another domain class (even if it only has a String field in it) and associate it in your first domain class through a hasMany relationship ?

Note : if you have a good reason, then I agree with Burt's answer.

Comment: @Simon it creates a tinyblob column in the table.


@Phillpe I guess I could create a separate object, but that seems wasteful.  The reason for the String[] field is just a list of features that describe this object.  I then want to be able to display them in a bulleted list.

Comment: a good reason not to have a new domain object and table is to avoid a join when you are retrieving the data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run 'grails install-templates' you can edit src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template which is where the HTML generation for editors is defined. Add in a new "else if" for String[]:

```
else if (property.type == String[].class)
    out << renderStringArrayEditor(domainClass, property)
```

and implement renderStringArrayEditor however you think best:

```
private renderStringArrayEditor(domainClass, property) {
...
}
```

I have no idea what HTML to use, but I might go with a textarea and split on \n. Whatever you decide on, you'll need to convert the input parameter to a String array in your controller methods.

If you're already run 'grails generate-all' or 'grails generate-views' you'll need to run 'grails generate-views' to regenerate your GSPs with the new editor.

Comment: I think I'll try this out.  It may be that I'm doing the wrong thing here, but hey, I'm still learning this framework. Thx.

Comment: Turns out that I ended up not doing it this way, but rather taking Phillpe's advice.  So I created a separate object that represents a "feature" and got it working.  I really didn't want to mess with the renderEditor.template file, although now I understand a whole lot more about how Grails works on the backend.